# How to make a Nested Layout (any Relative or Linear) transparent? Have a look at the pics and the code

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` on top of a `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayout` has a background image. I want to make the `RelativeLayout` transparent nicely.

I've used the alpha attribute, but the desired effect is not achieved.
Here's the effect of alpha attribute.

[image: effect of alpha]

What I want is for the background image to be visible throughout the `Activity` in the background. Here's the original look that needs to be changed.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/green_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.test4.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        tools:context="com.example.android.test2.MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/movieImage"
                android:layout_width="166dp"
                android:layout_height="88dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.05"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/defaultimgg" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reject"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/accept"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/accept"
                android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
                android:text="Reject"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/accept"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/movieImage"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/movieImage"
                android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
                android:text="accept"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:text="idTxt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/movieImage"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/movieImage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/idTxt"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="Type Of Serves : "
                tools:text="textView5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txttypeofserves"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                android:text="TextView"
                tools:text="txttypeofserves" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txttypeofserves"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txttypeofserves"
                android:text="Addres : "
                tools:text="Address" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtaddres"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                android:text="TextView"
                tools:text="txtaddress" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtaddres"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtaddres"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtaddres"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:text="Date: "
                tools:text="Date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
                android:text="TextView"
                tools:text="txtdate" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtdate"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Time : "
                tools:text="time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txttime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView11"
                android:text="TextView"
                tools:text="txttime" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txttype1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/idTxt"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idTxt"
                android:src="@drawable/defaultimgg" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtrectype"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                tools:text="txtrectype" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txttype1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtrectype"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                tools:text="txtype1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txttotalloadingfee"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView12"
                android:text="TextView"
                tools:text="txttoatlloadingfree" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use android:alpha="0.5"  to your layout or show the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android- transparent RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460321/android-transparent-relativelayout)

Comment: the "alpha" attribute does not give the desired effect. Please check the attached pic

Comment: Have you tried it on the cardview?

Comment: I tried, but the effect is the same

Comment: I just tried it again, and IT WORKS.
it wasn't working this way before.

Answer (score 1):

I already have seen in the comment that you've tweaked the alpha attribute to make it work. But anyway, as far as I have understood from your question you want to make your `CardView` to be transparent. So you might consider setting the background colour of your `CardView` as transparent by adding the following attribute in your `CardView`.

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

So the final `CardView` should look like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.test2.MainActivity">

    <!-- Other UI elements here -->

</CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem if you set an alpha then text also become transparent and here i found solution ..paste below code it working find i put one more relative layout only for background and i make cardview and main relative become transparent so adjust alpha in relLayoutextra layout.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.test4.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"

    tools:context="com.example.android.test2.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutextra"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:weightSum="1">
        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movieImage"
            android:layout_width="166dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/defaultimgg" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/accept"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/accept"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:text="Reject"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/accept"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/movieImage"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/movieImage"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:text="accept"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:text="idTxt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/movieImage"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/movieImage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/idTxt"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="Type Of Serves : "
            tools:text="textView5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttypeofserves"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:text="txttypeofserves" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txttypeofserves"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txttypeofserves"
            android:text="Addres : "
            tools:text="Address" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtaddres"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:text="txtaddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtaddres"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtaddres"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtaddres"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="Date: "
            tools:text="Date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:text="txtdate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtdate"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Time : "
            tools:text="time" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView11"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:text="txttime" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txttype1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/idTxt"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idTxt"
            android:src="@drawable/defaultimgg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtrectype"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:text="txtrectype" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttype1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtrectype"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:text="txtype1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttotalloadingfee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView12"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:text="txttoatlloadingfree" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```